# speeding up the xml parsing process using lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xml, pandas, parsing, lxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <document DateTime="2017-06-23T04:27:08.592Z">
       <PeakInfo No="1" mz="505.2315648572003965"
                 Intensity="4531.0000000000000000"
                 Rel_Intensity="3.2737729673489735"
                 Resolution="1879.5638812957554364"
                 SNR="14.0278637770897561"
                 Area="1348.1007591467391649"
                 Rel_Area="2.3371194184605959"
                 Index="238.9999999999976694"/>
       <PeakInfo No="2" mz="522.1330917856538463"
                 Intensity="3382.0000000000000000"
                 Rel_Intensity="2.4435886505350317"
                 Resolution="3502.9921209527169594"
                 SNR="10.4705882352940982"
                 Area="881.4468100654634100"
                 Rel_Area="1.5281101521284057"
                 Index="925.0000000000000000"/>
   </document>
```

Above is a part of an xml file that I have been working with lately. Each file contains more than 400 PeakInfo's, and I did make a python script to parse each file:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import pandas.io.formats.excel

full_path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')
newfolder = full_path+'\\xls files'
os.chdir(full_path)
os.makedirs(newfolder)

data = {}
for files in os.listdir(full_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(full_path, files)):
            plist = pd.DataFrame()
            filename = os.path.basename(files).rpartition('.')[0]

            if len(filename) == 2:
                filename = filename[:1]+'0'+filename[1:]

            xmlp = etree.parse(files)
            for p in xmlp.xpath('//PeakInfo'):
                data['Exp. m/z'] = p.attrib['mz']
                data['Intensity'] = p.attrib['Intensity']
                plist = plist.append(data, ignore_index=True)
                plist['Exp. m/z'] = plist['Exp. m/z'].astype(float)
                plist['Exp. m/z'] = plist['Exp. m/z'].map('{:.4f}'.format)
                plist['Intensity'] = plist['Intensity'].astype(float)
                plist['Intensity'] = plist['Intensity'].map('{:.0f}'.format)
                pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
                plist.to_excel(os.path.join(newfolder, filename+'.xls'),index=False)
```

This code changes the filename if it has only two characters (i.e. A1 to A01), and then pulls mz and Intensity and save as xls files. The problem is that parsing each file takes too long. Are there any tip of speeding the process up significantly?

Comment: This is the worst scenario to work with`pandas`. Use a XML Parser and write to Excel using a `xlsx package`.

Comment: @stovfl what do you mean by xlsx package? do you mean openpyxl or something?

Comment: Yes, `openpyxl` for example can write direct to `xlsx`.

Comment: My code would have to collect two columns out of the xml files and then write to xls, and I don't need to create dfs to do so? Sorry I am still a bit new to Python

Comment: Yes, [SO Answer Solution using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596222/7414759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import pandas.io.formats.excel

full_path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')
newfolder = full_path+'\\xls files'
os.chdir(full_path)
os.makedirs(newfolder)

data = {}
for files in os.listdir(full_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(full_path, files)):
            plist = pd.DataFrame()
            filename = os.path.basename(files).rpartition('.')[0]

            if len(filename) == 2:
                filename = filename[:1]+'0'+filename[1:]

            xmlp = etree.parse(files)
            for p in xmlp.xpath('//PeakInfo'):
                data['Exp. m/z'] = p.attrib['mz']
                data['Intensity'] = p.attrib['Intensity']
                plist = plist.append(data, ignore_index=True)
plist['Exp. m/z'] = plist['Exp. m/z'].astype(float)
plist['Exp. m/z'] = plist['Exp. m/z'].map('{:.4f}'.format)
plist['Intensity'] = plist['Intensity'].astype(float)
plist['Intensity'] = plist['Intensity'].map('{:.0f}'.format)
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
plist.to_excel(os.path.join(newfolder, filename+'.xls'),index=False)
```

just change the space,you code like `to_excel`execute too many time,and it's slow,and "astype" will copy element,and take too much memory then slow the speed.

Comment: For some reason I thought I needed the exporting lines to be within the for loop. Simply changing the spacing seems to be working much better. Thanks!

Comment: IO is a very slow operation,so next time consider more carefully.@BongKyoSeo

Answer (score 0):

You could try using C implementation of ElementTree http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm

According to the doc

> cElementTree is 15-20 times faster than the Python version of
>   ElementTree, and uses 2-5 times less memory.

Comment: OP is already using `lxml`, not the stdlib ElementTree. (See http://lxml.de/performance.html)

Comment: Changing `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` to `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET` doesn't seem to improve the speed for me. Each xml file does have roughly 5000+ data points, and my code pulls out ~1000 data points then saves as xls file.